# Keep Mongo DB set up up and running with two data center always

Tags: replication, mongodb-3.2

There is a scenario where we have 5 member replica set across two data centers.
Data center 1 : 3 Members
Data center 2 : 2 Members
Situation is if DC 1 goes down DC 2 becomes read only but  we need to keep it ready to accept writes also.
Is there any possibility for same using one extra member like hidden node or two arbiter.
We do not have third data center.

Thanks
Virendra Agarwal

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/130585/replicaset-with-mongodb-two-datacenters-one-primary-and-the-other-secondary) answer?

Comment: Yup i saw that answer that's why i mentioned hidden server here as non voting member the issue is if we have all priority zero members then we will need manual intervention and for longer period as we need to reconfigure whole set up in dc2 i was looking for another simpler way if possible. Still waiting if someone has achieved it by minimal configuration change

Comment: I will send you a detail configuration later today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With two DC's "getting working solution" it's always something "not recommended for mongodb".  That third DC is not a big deal. It is just arbiter in some XS size VPS what will cost you 15€/year. Like http://www.time4vps.eu  So, working solution is 4 data bearing node and one arbiter (2+2+1). One DC can always go down and replica set still keeps serving.

Comment: split brain will it work for that scenario too ?

Comment: @viren you mean that arbiter can see all mongod:s but those two DC:s cannot see each other? Arbiter can give it's vote to only one node. Without that arbiter vote, node cannot become primary. (no majority)

Comment: @JJussi if DC2 goes down, DC1 cannot hold election since it will have minority number of members 2/5 if I understand well how this work isn't it? But if DC1 goes down DC2 can elect a new master because they have the majority number of members 3/5. Kindly enlighten us on how you got this to work. Been pulling my hair with different scenarios but haven't tried this one yet

Comment: @blacksensei you are right. That's why I wrote that minimun good solution is three DC where that third DC is just minimum size VPS for arbiter.

Comment: Right, thanks for the clarifications. I will implement this and revert if possible. But I am sure it will work

Answer (score 0):

This is a configuration will work with using `Virtual Host Names` for config and arbiters. When you bring up the hidden ones you only need to change DNS entries to point to DC2 servers.

[image]